# Replacement - Codewars Algorithm Challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

[This Codewars Challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/598d89971928a085c000001a/train/javascript) asks you to

> Choose exactly one element from the sequence and replace it with another integer > 0. You are not allowed to replace a number with itself, or to change no number at all.

My thought process is to sort the input array from least to greatest, add `1` to the front, and then remove the greatest element from the array. This should result in the lowest possible sequence, since I'm basically swapping the greatest element with 1.

Examples:

```
([1,2,3,4,5]) => [1,1,2,3,4]

([4,2,1,3,5]) => [1,1,2,3,4]

([2,3,4,5,6]) => [1,2,3,4,5]

([2,2,2]) => [1,2,2]

([42]) => [1]
```

I tried:

```js
function replacement(a){
  let sorted = a.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  sorted.unshift(1);
  return sorted.slice(0, sorted.length -1);
}

console.log(replacement([2,3,4,5,6]));
```

which is working for the tests that are mentioned above, but seems to be failing 2 / 109.

```
wrong answer in test a=[1,1,1,1] - Expected: [1, 1, 2], instead got: [1, 1, 1]
wrong answer in test a=[1,1] - Expected: [2], instead got: [1]
```

I don't understand why my code is failing those tests - Codewars doesn't show what the entry sequence is for the tests that are failing. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think if max is 1, you have to replace it with 2. That should be it.

Comment: Thank you! Just realizing this after posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vivek pointed out, I was just missing a check to see if the max is `1`. If it is, I just need to replace it with `2`, that's all.

```js
function replacement(a){
  let sorted = a.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  if (sorted[sorted.length - 1] === 1){
    sorted.pop();
    sorted.push(2);
    return sorted;
  }
  sorted.unshift(1);
  return sorted.slice(0, sorted.length -1);
}

console.log(replacement([1, 1, 1, 1]));
```